# reading multiple xml files from a folder and name them

Tags: r, xml

Hello guys I just have a folder with approximately 20 xml files(eg. a.xml, b.xml, c.xml etc). I would like to read all these xml files and i would like to get the names for example the a.xml to a data list and so on. I tried the following:

```
list.files(path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE,
           full.names = FALSE)
```

but it reads them as values and not as list in the data of the enviroment so i cannot set the names i want.
any suggestion?

Comment: To convert to a list use the “as.list()” function. https://www.statology.org/r-convert-vector-to-list/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but after that how i can make all these lists as seperate lists?

Comment: You do not want to do that.  It is best to keep the file names as a list or vector so that you can loop (lapply or for loop) through the to open and process them.